# Convert Table To Excel in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a problem in convert `tabletoexcel`, when I use convert table to excel in main script section, it works correctly like this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel/1.1.0/dist/jquery.table2excel.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
   $("#MyTableID").table2excel({
                    filename: "tab2exl"
                }); 
    </script>
```

but when I want to use `table2excel` in function click it not work anymore, how can I solve this problem?

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(function () {
        $("#MyButtonID").click(function () {
            $("#MyTableID").table2excel({
                filename: "tab2exl"
            });
        })
    });

</script>
```

Comment: the $("#MyButtonID").click(function () {} is working or not

Answer (score 0):

Just refer this URl..
It has the same scenario that you want
like

```
<button>Export</button>
```

and in your js

```
$("button").click(function(){
$("#table2excel").table2excel({
// exclude CSS class
exclude:".noExl",
name:"Worksheet Name",
filename:"SomeFile",//do not include extension
fileext:".xls" // file extension
  });
});
```

and in your .cshtm/html

```
<tr class="noExl">
  <th>#</th>
  <th>Column heading</th>
  <th>Column heading</th>
 <th>Column heading</th>
```

https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Export-Html-Table-To-Excel-Spreadsheet-using-jQuery-table2excel.html

Comment: i dont have any problem when i use table2excel out of function but i can`t use it inside call function

Comment: @MiadBayanirad.have you followed the url i have mentioned..it has demo itself as per requiremnet